# Knowing in advance if re-captcha is going to be triggered (invisible V2, V3)

Tags: html, invisible-recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

After reading some documentation, I figured out that the re-captcha risk-analysis of invisible re-captcha V2 and V3 is triggered just after that the user clicks on submit buttons. Then, according to the output of the risk-analysis system, is asked a challenge (or not) to be solved by the user. Once that the challenge has been solved, the re-captcha token populates the innerHTML of "g.recaptcha.response".

Does it work in this way right? Is it not possible knowing if the captcha-challenge is going to be triggered (or not) before of the event that activates the risk-analysis system of captcha?

I mean, are there parameters of the DOM that tell you if the captcha-challenge is going to be asked?

Comment: _are there parameters of the DOM that tell you if the captcha-challenge is going to be asked?_ I doubt it, because such parameters in principle would defeat the purpose of captcha. Hypothetically you could  implement proprietary risk-analysis algorithms yourself. But this is hardly-doable and may have legal issues, so probably best answer is no, you can't do that.

Comment: If you would tell us why you need it, we might be able to offer some kind of alternative.

Comment: I'm practicing with web-scraping: in this case I want to log in https://www.therocktrading.com/en/login with the credentials of my account, but I want to know in advance if it'll ask me a captcha-challenge or not